# Didn't Find the Required Zlib Library

Tags: c++, zlib

I'm using a code written in C++, i have a problem regarding the compilation which is that my project is 64 bit, and I'm using zlib.lib, which will generate the error.

> module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'

I didn't find GNU 64 bit, but what i need is only the zlib.lib as 64 bit, does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"target machine type 'x86'" looks as if you need to change a compiler option from x86 target to 64 target...